# pyspark split array type column to multiple columns

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

After running ALS algorithm in pyspark over a dataset, I have come across a final dataframe which looks like the following

[image]

Recommendation column is array type, now I want to split this column, my final dataframe should look like this

[image]

Can anyone suggest me, which pyspark function can be used to form this dataframe?

Schema of the dataframe

```
root
 |-- person: string (nullable = false)
 |-- recommendation: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- ID: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- rating: float (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Can you share the schema of your data frame with `df.printSchema()` ?

Comment: @Psidom, I have added it in the question after your comment, please have a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming ID doesn't duplicate in each array, you can try the following:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df.withColumn('recommendation', f.explode('recommendation'))\
    .withColumn('ID', f.col('recommendation').getItem('ID'))\
    .withColumn('rating', f.col('recommendation').getItem('rating'))\
    .groupby('person')\
    .pivot('ID')\
    .agg(f.first('rating')).show()

+------+---+---+---+
|person|  a|  b|  c|
+------+---+---+---+
|   xyz|0.4|0.3|0.3|
|   abc|0.5|0.3|0.2|
|   def|0.3|0.2|0.5|
+------+---+---+---+
```

Or transform with RDD:

```
df.rdd.map(lambda r: Row(
    person=r.person, **{s.ID: s.rating for s in r.recommendation})
).toDF().show()

+------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|person|                  a|                  b|                  c|
+------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|   abc|                0.5|0.30000001192092896|0.20000000298023224|
|   def|0.30000001192092896|0.20000000298023224|                0.5|
|   xyz| 0.4000000059604645|0.30000001192092896|0.30000001192092896|
+------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Spot on @Psidom, Thanks a lot.